# React Filtering based on user input -State, setState, useState, Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a fun project that is filter data using .filter .map etc etc - At the moment I have a select -> option that changes the state of the data presented to the user but I also want to filter based an onChange event but have issues with the whole filter part

https://j121b.csb.app/ is the code sandbox and this is the issue:

[Type Error - data.instName.contains is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHOS5.png)

Could someone look over code and point me in the right direction please? Thank you and happy Friday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I sorted it - https://j121b.csb.app/ Look at the different states!

Answer (score 0):

Use `includes` instead of `contains`.